# Google Directions Error: request is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using directions for Google Maps V3 API. However I get the javscript error when i run it:
    Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

This is my JS code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionDisplay; //NEW CODE

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); //NEW CODE

    function initialize() {

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); //NEW CODE

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733);

    var options = {  

        zoom: 16,  

        center: latlng,  

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        scrollwheel: true

    }; 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);  

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

            map: map

        }); 

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({  

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

            map: map

        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseout", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function(event) {

            window.location = "http://localhost/yupsg/places/display/111";

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseover", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|ffffff|c41200");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseout", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|c41200|ffffff");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(event) {

            window.location = "http://localhost/yupsg/places/display/111";

        });

        var LatLngList = [

        new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

        new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733)

        ];

    }



        function changeMarkerOnmouseover(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200");

        }

        function changeMarkerOnmouseout(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff");

        }



        function changeMarkerOnmouseover(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|ffffff|c41200");

        }

        function changeMarkerOnmouseout(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|c41200|ffffff");

        }

                        //NEW CODE FOR NEW FUNCTION
        function calcRoute() {

            var start = "35 Oxford Street, Cambridge, MA 02138";

            var end = "24 Oxford Street, Cambridge, MA 02138";

            var request = {

                origin:start,

                destination:end,

                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

            };
        }

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

            }

          });



</script></head>
```

Comment: I just amended my answer below to include a hopefully-helpful near-minimal set of changes to get your code working.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `request` inside the scope of `calcRoute()` but then trying to use it outside immedately afterwards outside of `calcRoute()`.  Define it in the same scope where you will use it.

It appears that there might be a few other errors in there too.  Here's the end result of my trying to make minimal edits to get your code to work.  Hope it helps!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maps Test</title>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Map</h1>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var directionsDisplay; //NEW CODE

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); //NEW CODE

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); //NEW CODE

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733);

    var options = {  

        zoom: 16,  

        center: latlng,  

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

        scrollwheel: true
    }; 


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);  

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

            map: map

        }); 

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({  

            position: new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

            map: map

        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseover", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "mouseout", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function(event) {

            window.location = "http://localhost/yupsg/places/display/111";

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseover", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|ffffff|c41200");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "mouseout", function(event) {

            this.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|c41200|ffffff");

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function(event) {

            window.location = "http://localhost/yupsg/places/display/111";

        });

        var LatLngList = [

        new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733),

        new google.maps.LatLng(1.288693,103.846733)

        ];




        function changeMarkerOnmouseover(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|ffffff|c41200");

        }

        function changeMarkerOnmouseout(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=1|c41200|ffffff");

        }



        function changeMarkerOnmouseover(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|ffffff|c41200");

        }

        function changeMarkerOnmouseout(marker) {

            marker.setIcon("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=2|c41200|ffffff");

        }


            var start = "35 Oxford Street, Cambridge, MA 02138";

            var end = "24 Oxford Street, Cambridge, MA 02138";

            var request = {

                origin:start,

                destination:end,

                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

            };

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

            }

          });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```